# application/octet-stream blocks browser

Tags: php, download

I have written a small download portal and I use application/octet-stream to download the files.

```
function fu($filename)
{
     header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");  
     $save_as_name = basename($filename);   
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$save_as_name\""); 
     readfile($filename);   
}
```

When I am downloading a large file it is not possible to browse through the directory tree until the download has finished.

Is there any chance to do this in parallel?

Comment: Where are you browsing the directory tree, on the server or on the client?

Comment: it is a seperate php website which uses readdir() to view the directory tree.

Comment: Are you using sessions?

Comment: for which usage? in general: yes I do

Comment: Do you have a session open while running the download? If you are, can you not open one in that case
? Scripts with sessions open are blocking

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using sessions. While you have a session open in Window A which is busy serving the download Window B will not be able to get any pages because the PHP process serving A still has the session data open/locked and B is waiting on that lock to be released.

The simple solution is to call [`session_write_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) at some point before you call `readfile()`. This will commit the session to disk on the server, close it, and release the lock so other PHP processes can pick it back up.

Comment: hi Sammitch, thanks for your answer. I will test session_wrote_close() during the weekend and give you a feedback.